# Redirect to another page in Asp.NEt MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an application using ASP.NET MVC4 approach. I have a aspx page that is associated to a controller. On the page, I have a link. What I want to do is upon clicking this link I want to redirect to another aspx page which is associated to another controller. How can I achieve this.?

Comment: Redirect or navigate to?

Comment: Use RedirectionToAction method

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public RedirectResult RedirectToAspx()
{
        return Redirect("/pages/index.aspx");
}
```

Also in your view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Redirect", "RedirectToAspx")
```

Comment: Able to do it using Html.RoutLink("Link Text", new {action ="action", controller = "controller"}) in the aspx page.

Comment: ohh. Sorry. I am absolutely new to asp.net and MVC. My mistake.